# Using PCA to reduce dimensionality of multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, pca

I have multiple (12000) multivariate time series datasets.  Each MTS has 4 dimensions and 3500 time-points.

I want to reduce each MTS into a single vector of features using PCA.
As far as I've seen, in a lot of cases dataset is reduced using PCA either by dimensions or time points. But not both.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is 3-order tensor (no_examples x no_features x no_time_steps), so as you remarked, you can't use just PCA which works for matrices (matrices are 2-tensors, since a matrix $M = (M_{ij})_{i < n, j < m} = \sum_{i < n, j < m} M_{ij} e_i^T e'_j$)

You can use a technique that is called [higher-order, or tensor, SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition). This technique is a generalization of SVD to higher order tensors.

In R there is a package [rTensor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rTensor/rTensor.pdf) which seems to be aimed at this.

Comment: On this site we prefer longer, self-contained answers.  Could you please extend this answer?